# Update строки

Tags: oracle, sql

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать запрос, который выбирает select'ом несколько строк из БД и обновляет update'ит запись одного поля значением другого поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. select * from table where rownum<10;
2. update table set col1=col2

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще так:

```
CREATE  TABLE TABLE1 (f1 INT)
CREATE TABLE table2 (f1 int)
INSERT TABLE1 (f1) VALUES (23)
INSERT TABLE2(f1)
VALUES
  (2324)

update TABLE2 SET table2.f1=(SELECT f1 FROM TABLE1) 
SELECT * FROM table2
```